# How to do nested dynamic routing in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, routes, gatsby, reach-router

I would like a URL structure in my app like:

```
// Example
https://simplywall.st/stocks/us/tech/nasdaq-aapl/apple

// Route example with params
https://simplywall.st/stocks/:countryCode/:sector/:index/:companyName
```

How would you make a **nested** folder structure [like this](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/examples/gatsbygram/src/pages) in Gatsby? Ideally, I would love a modal to show the company information if `/:index` is a list of stocks.

As this feels wrong and I'm not even sure if it's possible...

```
src
  /pages
    /stocks
      index.tsx
      /{countryCode}
        index.tsx
        /{sector}
          index.tsx
```